# Mongo mongoose - Can I check a field in a model after an update happened inside the same query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to check a field in a model after an update happened inside the same query?

I have the following schema:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String
    },
    reports: [ReportSchema],
    hasReports: false (or true)
...
})

mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

const reportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    title: {
        type: String,
    },
    ...
});
```

When I update the product I can add or remove reports. When I remove, I could end up with less reports (then hasReports would be still true) or end up removing the last report, then hasReports should be false.

```
await Station.updateOne({
        "name": productName
    },
    {
        "$pull": {
            "reports": {
                "someField": someField
            }
        }
})
```

I want to avoid having to make a new query (findOneAndUpdate or so) just to access AGAIN same product to check if the reports array is empty. Can I do it somehow within the above query? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation form of update to have a second $set operation:

```
Station.updateOne({
  "name": "productName"
},
[
  {"$set": {
      "reports": {$filter: {
          input: "$reports",
          cond: {$eq: ["$someField","someField"]}
      }}
  }},
  {$set: {
      hasReports: {$ne: ["$reports",[]]}
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qloQ8BfXK9T)